# Wrong prediction with Keras network but good accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm programming a CNN with keras, to predict chemical elements' emission spectrum. I have the photos classified in different folders with the name of the element and I'm using Image Data generator. The dataset is quite small, but I've it divided in train, test and validation. I got accuracy higher than 90 in the three sets, but when I pass the photos one by one the prediction is wrong. It classifies them well (for example, most of B are classified as Be or Hg as Zn), so I think the problem is that I don't know how to get the class.

**The code I'm using is this:**

```
dir="datasets//con_espectro//test_ski//"
elem=sorted(os.listdir(dir))
l=len(elem)
for i in range(0,l):
    for pos in range(1,10):
        im=cv2.imread(dir+elem[i]+"//"+elem[i]+"_"+str(pos)+"_i2_d_tes.jpg")
        a=np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(im/255,(500,500)),axis=0)
        b=np.argmax(modelo.predict(a))
        if b!=i:
            print(elem[i]+"  "+str(pos)+"  -->   "+elem[b])
```

**Result:**

```
0B  1  -->   Be
0B  2  -->   Be
0B  4  -->   Be
0B  5  -->   Be
0B  6  -->   Li
0B  7  -->   Be
0B  9  -->   Be
0C  1  -->   Au
0C  2  -->   0S
0C  3  -->   Au
0C  4  -->   Au
0C  5  -->   Au
0C  6  -->   Ag
```

**And for the training:**

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=90,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True)

test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory("datasets//con_espectro//train_ski//",target_size=(500,500),batch_size=97)
val_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_directory("datasets//con_espectro//validation_ski//",target_size=(500,500),batch_size=97)
test_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_directory("datasets//con_espectro//test_ski//",target_size=(500,500),batch_size=97)

model=models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape=(500,500,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512,activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(97,activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=20),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath='modelos_con//1000.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]
history=model.fit(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=27,epochs=100,validation_data=val_generator,validation_steps=9,callbacks=callbacks)

model.evaluate(test_generator)
```

Thank you very much,
Zumo

Comment: Try `label_map = test_datagen.class_indices` to get what indices correspond to each class or just to `model.predict_classes(x)` if you have Sequential model

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it's not working. The classes are organized alphabetically, and predict_calsses is giving back the same than my way (I change to this way that is better). I suppose the problem is in the training that maybe it has changed the order of the classes, but I don't know

Comment: A negative result is also result. Then you can try to take a couple of batches from train generator, and evaluate model on them, and compare labels. If there's a label mismatch, you will restore the right label sequence and validate it on the second batch. If model has strong overfit, you will then not able to predict on your data. If the results are garbage even on the training samples, that you will need to check the training procedure

Comment: Ok, I’m studying the result on the training dataset. In a first look seems as I said, similar categories than testing, but I will do a deeper study. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "sigmoid" activation in the final layer than you should use loss= "binary_crossentropy" when you compile it .